# modifying JSON value

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, str-replace

I'm trying to modify a value in a JSON file, I tried the following code but it is not changing anything so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

```
def file_filtering(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        f.close()
    for elem in data['features']:
        elem = elem[:-1]
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '), sort_keys=False)
        f.close()
```

I'm trying to change the URL by simply removing the last character '/', without deleting the values under the URL.

```
 "features": {
        "https://services.runescape.com-ow.top/weblogin/loginForm/": {
            "activex_count": 0,
            "addeventlistener_count": 0,
            "alert_count": 0,
        }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `f.close()` if you're using a context manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `elem = elem[:-1]` is simply changing the `elem` variable and not really changing the key of the dictionary.

Generally, changing a key from a dictionary in place is hard... It's much easier to just create a new dictionary altogether. You can do so with a *dict comprehension*, such as:

```
{key[:-1]: value for key, value in data['features'].items()}
```

Which you can replace in the JSON data with:

```
data['features'] = {
    key[:-1]: value
    for key, value in data['features'].items()}
```

You can do slightly better, rather than chopping the last character of the key, you can explicitly strip it of slashes at the end, using `rstrip()`:

```
data['features'] = {
    key.rstrip('/'): value
    for key, value in data['features'].items()}
```

Putting it all together:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
data['features'] = {
    key.rstrip('/'): value
    for key, value in data['features'].items()}
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '), sort_keys=False)
```

Note that you don't need to call `f.close()` explicitly, opening a file in a context manager (as the `with` statement does) takes care of closing it automatically once you leave it.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, had to put `.items()` because of `too many values to unpack` error

Comment: @rahaf Ah yes my mistake! Thanks for pointing it out. I'll update the answer.